# color dropdown with its color in dynamic dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm using bootstrap form to add a printer, Based on the process, material will chosen and then respective color should be chosen. These all process is working fine with dynamic dropdown. But I want to display along with color so that the user will get correct idea which color he is choosing.
Please guide me how to pass color with its respective color from the script. User should be able to see which color he is adding.

[image: dynamic dropdown]

```js
  <script language="javascript">
function fillCategory(){ 
 // this function is used to fill the category list on load
addOption(document.drop_list.Category, "FDM", "FDM", "");
addOption(document.drop_list.Category, "SLA", "SLA", "");
addOption(document.drop_list.Category, "SLS", "SLS", "");
}

function SelectSubCat(){
// ON selection of category this function will work

removeAllOptions(document.drop_list.SubCat);
addOption(document.drop_list.SubCat, "", "Material", "");

if(document.drop_list.Category.value == 'FDM'){
addOption(document.drop_list.SubCat,"ABS", "ABS");
addOption(document.drop_list.SubCat,"PLA", "PLA");
addOption(document.drop_list.SubCat,"Nylon", "Nylon");
addOption(document.drop_list.SubCat,"Hips", "Hips");
addOption(document.drop_list.SubCat,"PC", "PC");
addOption(document.drop_list.SubCat,"Flex", "Flex");
addOption(document.drop_list.SubCat,"Wood Fill PLA", "Wood Fill PLA");
addOption(document.drop_list.SubCat,"Carbon Fiber", "Carbon Fiber");
addOption(document.drop_list.SubCat,"ABS+", "ABS+");
}
if(document.drop_list.Category.value == 'SLA'){
addOption(document.drop_list.SubCat,"Clear Resin", "Clear Resin");
addOption(document.drop_list.SubCat,"ABS Like", "ABS Like");
addOption(document.drop_list.SubCat,"Flex", "Flex");
addOption(document.drop_list.SubCat,"Castable Resin", "Castable Resin");
}
if(document.drop_list.Category.value == 'SLS'){
addOption(document.drop_list.SubCat,"Nylon 12", "Nylon 12");

}

}
function SelectSubCat1(){
// ON selection of category this function will work

removeAllOptions(document.drop_list.SubCat1);
addOption(document.drop_list.SubCat1, "", "Color", "");

if(document.drop_list.Category.value == 'FDM' && document.drop_list.SubCat.value != 'Wood Fill PLA'){
addOption(document.drop_list.SubCat1,"White", "White");
addOption(document.drop_list.SubCat1,"Black", "Black");
addOption(document.drop_list.SubCat1,"Blue", "Blue");
addOption(document.drop_list.SubCat1,"Red", "Red");
addOption(document.drop_list.SubCat1,"Green", "Green");
addOption(document.drop_list.SubCat1,"Grey", "Grey");
addOption(document.drop_list.SubCat1,"Orange", "Orange");
addOption(document.drop_list.SubCat1,"Yellow", "Yellow");
addOption(document.drop_list.SubCat1,"Silver", "Silver");
addOption(document.drop_list.SubCat1,"Glow-in-the-dark", "Glow-in-the-dark");
addOption(document.drop_list.SubCat1,"Purple", "Purple");
addOption(document.drop_list.SubCat1,"Gold", "Gold");
addOption(document.drop_list.SubCat1,"Brown", "Brown");
addOption(document.drop_list.SubCat1,"Pink", "Pink");
}
if(document.drop_list.SubCat.value == 'Wood Fill PLA'){
addOption(document.drop_list.SubCat1,"Brown", "Brown");
}

if(document.drop_list.SubCat.value == 'ABS Like'){
addOption(document.drop_list.SubCat1,"White", "White");
addOption(document.drop_list.SubCat1,"Black", "Black");
addOption(document.drop_list.SubCat1,"Grey", "Grey");
}

if(document.drop_list.SubCat.value == 'Nylon 12'){
addOption(document.drop_list.SubCat1,"White", "White");
}
if(document.drop_list.SubCat.value == 'Clear Resin'){
addOption(document.drop_list.SubCat1,"Transparent/clear", "Transparent/clear");
}
if(document.drop_list.SubCat.value == 'Flex'){
addOption(document.drop_list.SubCat1,"Transparent/clear", "Transparent/clear");
}
if(document.drop_list.SubCat.value == 'Castable Resin'){
addOption(document.drop_list.SubCat1,"Transparent/clear", "Transparent/clear");
}

}
////////////////// 

function removeAllOptions(selectbox)
{
 var i;
 for(i=selectbox.options.length-1;i>=0;i--)
 {
  //selectbox.options.remove(i);
  selectbox.remove(i);
 }
}


function addOption(selectbox, value, text )
{
 var optn = document.createElement("OPTION");
 optn.text = text;
 optn.value = value;
 
 selectbox.options.add(optn);
}

</script>
```

```html
<?php
session_start();
if(empty($_SESSION)){
header("Location: ../login.php");
exit(); }
$mpage = "printer";
$page = "add_printer.php";
include '../header.php';
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 


  <!-- Content Wrapper. Contains page content -->
  <div class="content-wrapper">
    <!-- Content Header (Page header) -->
    <section class="content-header">
      <h1>
        ADD PRINTER
       
      </h1>
      <ol class="breadcrumb">
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Printer</a></li>
        <li class="active">Add Printer</li>
      </ol>
    </section>

 
 <body  onload="fillCategory();">
    <!-- Main content -->
    <section class="content">
 
 <div class="col-md-12">
  <div class="box box-info">
            <div class="box-header with-border">
              <h3 class="box-title">Printer Details</h3>
            </div>
            <!-- /.box-header -->
            <!-- form start -->
            <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" name="drop_list">
              <div class="box-body">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="inputname" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Printer Name</label>

                  <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputname" placeholder="Printer Name" name="printer_name">
                  </div>
                </div>
    
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="Process" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Process</label>
    
    <div class="col-sm-6">
    <SELECT  NAME="Category" class="form-control" onChange="SelectSubCat();" > 
    <Option value="">Process</option>
    </SELECT>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="Material" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Material</label>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
    <SELECT id="SubCat" NAME="SubCat[]" class="form-control" onChange="SelectSubCat1();" multiple>
    <Option value="">Material</option>
    
    </SELECT>
  
    </div>
    
    </div>
    
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="Color" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Color</label>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <SELECT id="SubCat1" NAME="SubCat1" class="form-control" >
    <option value="" disabled selected >Color</option>
    </SELECT>
       
    </div>
    
    </div>
    
    
    <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="quality" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Strength</label>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
      <select class="form-control" name="strength">
                  <option selected="selected">High</option>
                  <option >Mid</option>
                  <option>Low</option>
                  </select>
    </div>
    </div>
    
    
    
      <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="surfacefinish" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Surface Finish</label>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
      <select class="form-control" name="surface_finish">
                   <option selected="selected">High</option>
                  <option>Mid</option>
                  <option>Low</option>
                  </select>
    </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="per_gram_charge" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Per Gram Price&nbsp(Rs.) </label>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
    <input type="number"  class="form-control" id="per_gram_charge" step="0.01" name="per_gram_charge" placeholder="0.00">
    </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="per_hour_charge" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Per Hour Price&nbsp(Rs.) </label>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="per_hour_charge" step="0.01" name="per_hour_charge" placeholder="0.00">
    </div>
    </div>
      
    
              </div></div>
              <!-- /.box-body -->
              <div class="box-footer">
                
                <button type ="submit" name="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-info pull-right" >Add Printer</button>
              </div>
              <!-- /.box-footer -->
            </form></div>
   

    </div>
    
    </section>
 </body>

<?php

include '../footer.php';

?>


</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this.

```html
<select>
    <option value="1" style="background:red">Red</option>
    <option value="2" style="background:yellow">Yellow</option>
    <option value="3" style="background:purple">Purple</option>
</select>
```

Modify your addOption() method as below.
Provide color name while calling the below function

```
function addOption(selectbox, value, text, color) // added extra parameter color.
{
    var optn = document.createElement("OPTION");
    optn.text = text;
    optn.value = value;
    optn.style.backgroundColor = color; // added new statement
    selectbox.options.add(optn);
}
```

Call function as

```
  // passing 4th parameter as color blue.
    addOption(document.drop_list.SubCat1,"Blue", "Blue", "blue");
```

Comment: Sir, its dynamic dropdown, its getting values from script, how to add style in script

Comment: You can add the above style dynamically.

Comment: plz guide me, how to add it dynamically, i will very thankful

Comment: @rashmism : See I've updated the answer, make necessary changes in your code.

Answer (score 2):

You could modify your addOption function to add background color for each option. (Or give them a class)

```
function addOption(selectbox, value, text) {
  var optn = document.createElement("OPTION");
  optn.text = text;
  optn.value = value;
  if(optn.value != ('Transparent/clear' || 'Glow-in-the-dark')){
    optn.style.background = value
  }
  selectbox.options.add(optn)
}
```

Or you could do it in css

```
option[value="Black"] {
  background: black;
}

option[value="Red"] {
  background: red;
}

/* and so on... */
```

**demo**

```js
function addOption(selectbox, value, text) {
  var optn = document.createElement("OPTION");
  optn.text = text;
  optn.value = value;
  if(optn.value != ('Transparent/clear' || 'Glow-in-the-dark')){
    optn.style.background = value
  }
  selectbox.options.add(optn);
}

// Just for the demo
const selectBox = document.querySelector('select')
const colors = ['Red', 'Transparent/clear', 'Glow-in-the-dark', 'Blue', 'Goldenrod']

colors.forEach(color => addOption(selectBox, color, color))
```

```html
<select></select>
```